# Uninstalling program using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to uninstall a program/application from system automatically using power shell. When I googled first, advice was to use get-wmiobject and then use uninstall() function.

Code I used:

```
$app = get-wmiobject -Class Win32_Product | where-object ($_Name  -Like "part of product name"}
$app.uninstall()
```

Error message:
Screen shot attached.

[image: Error message]

Solution tried: Most of the blogs mentioned that not running as administrator would be the reason for the problem. But, I tried running the code as the administrator and still getting the error message. Any help would be useful.

Thanks,
Manoj Kumar

Comment: Are you trying this on a personal machine or company machine? For myself, this code works on most applications. But, there are certain ones that not even admin rights can remove from your machine due to policies put in place. These can be things like agents for server software, or antimalware agents, etc. Have you tried using this on multiple applications?

Comment: @CoryEtmund : I am trying on a company machine. I tried for other application(adobe) and it worked. So this command is not right for the application which I am using. Please let me know what could be next steps. The application I am trying to uninstall is my company's product.

Comment: I would make sure that you are allowed to remove this software before continuing.. you may be unable to do this because of policies put in place that keep the software from being removed, even when being removed with administrator priviledges. After that, the next question I would ask is what program are we trying to remove? Some applications come installed as an .exe but some are .msi, there are different ways to remove each type.

Comment: @CoryEtmund: Thank you for your reply. I will look if there are any policies that blocks my uninstallation process. I have an setup.exe file which I use to install the application. When manually trying to uninstall, when I click the progeam from "Add or remove programs" from control panel, I am given check box options(Modify/Remove), from which I select the remove option. Not sure if that's causing the issue here. If not, how this manual process of selecting "Remove" would happen in power shel?l

Comment: Programs are made differently, if you search around for powershell installation options for that particular program online you might just find the command is already written for you somewhere. Just do a little more research and see what you can find. Without knowing what program we are talking about, I don't believe I can help you any further

Comment: @Cory Etmund: Thank you for your reply..I resolved it. Thanks for your answers